# How to create a Online Word Processor also [ HTML/XML to .doc conversion in server using .net]

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vsto

I'm interested in knowing to create a Online Word processor similar to Google Docs and MS Office web Apps. i want to do it using MicroSoft technologies and Tools only. I'm a beginner in ASP.net and C#.net. I've planned to do its front end using TinyMCE [ http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php ]. but how to convert the data in the browser to .doc in the server? how can i do the formatting of a .doc file in the server using .net? what are the tools available in .net to work on such kind of projects? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use OpenXML to generate word docs. This is of course for Word 2007/2010, not 2003. PLenty of documentation on how to do it. You can reverse a word doc by changing extension from .docx to .zip then extracting the files and viewing them in notepad.

thinking about it more, you might want to create an XSLT to translate the html markup to OpenXML. But this is a lot of work (might already be available somewhere on the net) so you might try a 3rd party tool as suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of third-party libraries, such as Aspose, that can do this.
I don't think you'll find any good free ones.

You can generate `.docx` (OpenXML) files using the [OpenXML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx).